# One USB Host Controller, multiple internal root hubs?

Tags: usb

Does the USB technology allow (and support) a single UHC to have multiple root hubs ?

If so, do implementations exist ?

If yes, what would be an example of such a UHC ?

(What I'm not asking is whether a single host is allowed to have multiple UHCs.)

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/380091/what-is-the-difference-between-usb-root-hub-and-usb-host-controller is this helpful at all?

Comment: No. The top answer doesn't clearly address or answer my question. Of course, it says that there may be more than one root hub in a given system. This seems to merely reflect the possibility of having two or more UHCs in a system, with exactly one root hub per UCH.

Comment: My question arises because I don't understand whether the USB system ends/ begins in the root hub, inclusively, with UHC being just an intermediary between USB system(s) and host; or UHC is part of USB.

Comment: However, my strong guess is that UHC communicates with and controls one (or more!) USB systems by means of  a standardized interface (such as UHCI, OHCI, EHCI), respectively. If true, than UHC is just an intermediary, and with exactly one function: integrating one or more USB buses in host.

Comment: In this case UHC is NOT part of USB, although it may implement and maintain some USB interface in order to support any connected USB system.

Comment: Also, the designation 'USB Host Controller' really suggests an entity that is higher up in some hierarchy then USB itself.